# IE11 and Twitch?

Tags: internet-explorer

Is IE11+ supposed to be Twitch "friendly"? I just loaded up Twitch.tv on a fresh Windows 10 installation and switching between channels on the main jumbotron is completely mangled. A bit sad to say the least. I thought IE was turning it around.

Comment: Why would you use IE11 for anything other than browser support testing on windows 10, when you have access to Edge? or any of the other more modern browsers. (and, this is off topic for this site)

Comment: I updated from Windows 8.1 to 10 just a few days ago. I continue to get notices that my computer is low on memory (despite the fact that I have 16 gigs), so I was trying to use the browser with the lowest memory footprint while I was doing memory-intensive tasks. To be honest, I didn't know Microsoft Edge existed when I posted this; and yes, you're right, I probably shouldn't have let my frustration flow into Stack Overflow.